# Trailing slash lost on redirect_to protocol rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

A Rails 3 app with a redirect_to is losing the traling slash so that "/test.com/foo" is redirecting to "https://test.comfoo"

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :switch_to_ssl
def switch_to_ssl
  if ENV['RAILS_ENV']=="production" && !request.ssl?
        redirect_to :protocol=>"https://"
      end
end
```

Any ideas?